# How to set a time out in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

How to set a `time-out` in `spring cloud gateway`?

```
routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
        .route("test-api", r -> r.path("/api/**")).uri(apiLb))
        .route("test-doc", r -> r.path("/doc/**")).uri(docLb));
```

Is there a way to set a time out for just one `ROUTE` - `doc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Referred from spring doc

To set `global time-out`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 1000
        response-timeout: 5s
```

Per-route timeouts:-

```
  - id: per_route_timeouts
    uri: https://example.org
    predicates:
      - name: Path
        args:
          pattern: /delay/{timeout}
    metadata:
      response-timeout: 200
      connect-timeout: 200
```

In Java, add the below bean(s):

```
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.RouteMetadataUtils.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_ATTR;
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.RouteMetadataUtils.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_ATTR;

  

  @Bean
  public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder routeBuilder){
     return routeBuilder.routes()
           .route("test1", r -> {
              return r.host("*.somehost.org").and().path("/somepath")
                    .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("header1", "header-value-1"))
                    .uri("http://someuri")
                    .metadata(RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_ATTR, 200)
                    .metadata(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_ATTR, 200);
           })
           .build();
  }

@Bean
public ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory(
        final CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry, final TimeLimiterRegistry timeLimiterRegistry) {
    ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory = new 
            ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory(circuitBreakerRegistry, timeLimiterRegistry);
    reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory.configureDefault(id -> {
        CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = circuitBreakerRegistry.find(id).isPresent()
                ? circuitBreakerRegistry.find(id).get().getCircuitBreakerConfig()
                : circuitBreakerRegistry.getDefaultConfig();
        TimeLimiterConfig timeLimiterConfig = timeLimiterRegistry.find(id).isPresent()
                ? timeLimiterRegistry.find(id).get().getTimeLimiterConfig()
                : timeLimiterRegistry.getDefaultConfig();

        return new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id).circuitBreakerConfig(circuitBreakerConfig)
                .timeLimiterConfig(timeLimiterConfig).build();
    });
    return reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;
}
```

Comment: For me its not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64935162/spring-cloud-gate-request-timeout-not-working-for-path can you help me on it ?

Answer (score 5):

the accepted answer works *if* you are not using R4J circuitbreakers or timelimiters...but if you do, the above settings will be insufficient and in fact will be overridden by the R4J settings. it is discussed [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/issues/61) and [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1729), the current workaround as of this writing can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/issues/61#issuecomment-636414118)...basically, you write a custom bean so it will honor the configuration settings:

```java
@Bean
public ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory(final CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry, final TimeLimiterRegistry timeLimiterRegistry) {
        ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory = new ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory();
reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory.configureCircuitBreakerRegistry(circuitBreakerRegistry);
        reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory.configureDefault(id -> {
            CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = circuitBreakerRegistry.find(id).isPresent() ? circuitBreakerRegistry.find(id).get().getCircuitBreakerConfig()
                    : circuitBreakerRegistry.getDefaultConfig();
            TimeLimiterConfig timeLimiterConfig = timeLimiterRegistry.find(id).isPresent() ? timeLimiterRegistry.find(id).get().getTimeLimiterConfig()
                    : timeLimiterRegistry.getDefaultConfig();

            return new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                    .circuitBreakerConfig(circuitBreakerConfig)
                    .timeLimiterConfig(timeLimiterConfig)
                    .build();
        });
        return reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;
}
```

Comment: I think the accepted answer is correct for vanilla routes. If you insert a circuitBreaker you should check also the timeout of it

Comment: @TobiaZambon yes you are correct i will edit the answer to add that clarification.